# Explode dict from Pandas column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following df:

```
    movie_id    rating_all 
0   tt7653254   [{'age': 'all', 'avg_rating': 8.1, 'count': 109326}, {'age': '<18', 'avg_rating': 8.8, 'count': 318}, {'age': '18-29', 'avg_rating': 8.3, 'count': 29740}, {'age': '30-44', 'avg_rating': 8.0, 'count': 33012}, {'age': '45+', 'avg_rating': 7.7, 'count': 7875}]
1   tt8579674   [{'age': 'all', 'avg_rating': 8.6, 'count': 9420}, {'age': '<18', 'avg_rating': 9.1, 'count': 35}, {'age': '18-29', 'avg_rating': 8.7, 'count': 2437}, {'age': '30-44', 'avg_rating': 8.5, 'count': 2529}, {'age': '45+', 'avg_rating': 8.3, 'count': 960}]
2   tt7286456   [{'age': 'all', 'avg_rating': 8.6, 'count': 592441}, {'age': '<18', 'avg_rating': 9.1, 'count': 2244}, {'age': '18-29', 'avg_rating': 8.7, 'count': 160506}, {'age': '30-44', 'avg_rating': 8.5, 'count': 160158}, {'age': '45+', 'avg_rating': 8.3, 'count': 30451}]
3   tt1302006   [{'age': 'all', 'avg_rating': 8.1, 'count': 187675}, {'age': '<18', 'avg_rating': 8.7, 'count': 461}, {'age': '18-29', 'avg_rating': 8.3, 'count': 41951}, {'age': '30-44', 'avg_rating': 7.9, 'count': 59729}, {'age': '45+', 'avg_rating': 7.8, 'count': 18550}]
4   tt7131622   [{'age': 'all', 'avg_rating': 7.8, 'count': 323152}, {'age': '<18', 'avg_rating': 8.4, 'count': 955}, {'age': '18-29', 'avg_rating': 7.9, 'count': 82133}, {'age': '30-44', 'avg_rating': 7.6, 'count': 95878}, {'age': '45+', 'avg_rating': 7.5, 'count': 26383}]
5   tt8637428   [{'age': 'all', 'avg_rating': 7.7, 'count': 21362}, {'age': '<18', 'avg_rating': 8.0, 'count': 45}, {'age': '18-29', 'avg_rating': 7.9, 'count': 5901}, {'age': '30-44', 'avg_rating': 7.6, 'count': 6492}, {'age': '45+', 'avg_rating': 7.3, 'count': 2133}]
```

And I want to transform it to something like:

```
    movie_id    all_avg     all_count   <18_avg     <18_count   18-29_avg
0   tt7653254   8.1         109326      8.8         318         8.3
1   tt8579674   8.6         9420        9.1         35          8.7
2   tt7286456   8.6         592441      9.1         2244        8.7
3   tt1302006   8.1         187675      8.7         461         8.3
4   tt7131622   7.8         323152      8.4         955         7.9
5   tt8637428   7.7         21362       8           45          7.9
```

and so on...

I've tried

```
ratings.set_index('movie_id')['rating_all'].apply(pd.Series).reset_index()
```

and using

```
json_normalize(data, 
               record_path=['rating_all'], 
               meta=['movie_id']).set_index('movie_id')
```

but none give something similiar. Is there an easy way to explode the dictionary into columns?

Data to produce the DataFrame:

```
data = {'movie_id': ['tt7653254', 'tt8579674', 'tt7286456', 'tt1302006', 'tt7131622', 'tt8637428'], 
        'rating_all': [[{'age': 'all', 'avg_rating': 8.1, 'count': 109326},
                        {'age': '<18', 'avg_rating': 8.8, 'count': 318},   
                        {'age': '18-29', 'avg_rating': 8.3, 'count': 29740},
                        {'age': '30-44', 'avg_rating': 8.0, 'count': 33012},
                        {'age': '45+', 'avg_rating': 7.7, 'count': 7875}],
                       [{'age': 'all', 'avg_rating': 8.6, 'count': 9420},
                        {'age': '<18', 'avg_rating': 9.1, 'count': 35},
                        {'age': '18-29', 'avg_rating': 8.7, 'count': 2437},
                        {'age': '30-44', 'avg_rating': 8.5, 'count': 2529},
                        {'age': '45+', 'avg_rating': 8.3, 'count': 960}],
                       [{'age': 'all', 'avg_rating': 8.6, 'count': 592441},
                        {'age': '<18', 'avg_rating': 9.1, 'count': 2244},
                        {'age': '18-29', 'avg_rating': 8.7, 'count': 160506},
                        {'age': '30-44', 'avg_rating': 8.5, 'count': 160158},
                        {'age': '45+', 'avg_rating': 8.3, 'count': 30451}],
                       [{'age': 'all', 'avg_rating': 8.1, 'count': 187675},
                        {'age': '<18', 'avg_rating': 8.7, 'count': 461},
                        {'age': '18-29', 'avg_rating': 8.3, 'count': 41951},
                        {'age': '30-44', 'avg_rating': 7.9, 'count': 59729},
                        {'age': '45+', 'avg_rating': 7.8, 'count': 18550}],
                       [{'age': 'all', 'avg_rating': 7.8, 'count': 323152},
                        {'age': '<18', 'avg_rating': 8.4, 'count': 955},
                        {'age': '18-29', 'avg_rating': 7.9, 'count': 82133},
                        {'age': '30-44', 'avg_rating': 7.6, 'count': 95878},
                        {'age': '45+', 'avg_rating': 7.5, 'count': 26383}],
                       [{'age': 'all', 'avg_rating': 7.7, 'count': 21362},
                        {'age': '<18', 'avg_rating': 8.0, 'count': 45},
                        {'age': '18-29', 'avg_rating': 7.9, 'count': 5901},
                        {'age': '30-44', 'avg_rating': 7.6, 'count': 6492},
                        {'age': '45+', 'avg_rating': 7.3, 'count': 2133}]]}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming I've interpreted correctly what you're trying to do, you can achieve it as follows:

Starting from (*what I assume!!*) is your input dataset:

```
    movie_id                                            ratings
0  tt7653254  [{'age': 'all', 'avg_rating': 8.1, 'count': 10...
1  tt8579674  [{'age': 'all', 'avg_rating': 8.6, 'count': 94...
2  tt7286456  [{'age': 'all', 'avg_rating': 8.6, 'count': 59...
3  tt1302006  [{'age': 'all', 'avg_rating': 8.1, 'count': 18...
4  tt7131622  [{'age': 'all', 'avg_rating': 7.8, 'count': 32...
5  tt8637428  [{'age': 'all', 'avg_rating': 7.7, 'count': 21...
```

Where the ratings values are an actual list, not a string (if they're a string, `x['ratings'] = x.ratings.apply(eval)` to turn them into an object).

First you want to explode each of the rows in the list to be a set of rows:

```
parsed = x.groupby('movie_id').ratings.apply(lambda x: pd.DataFrame(x.values[0])).reset_index()
```

Which will give you:

```
> parsed.head(10)
    movie_id  level_1    age  avg_rating   count
0  tt1302006        0    all         8.1  187675
1  tt1302006        1    <18         8.7     461
2  tt1302006        2  18-29         8.3   41951
3  tt1302006        3  30-44         7.9   59729
4  tt1302006        4    45+         7.8   18550
5  tt7131622        0    all         7.8  323152
6  tt7131622        1    <18         8.4     955
7  tt7131622        2  18-29         7.9   82133
8  tt7131622        3  30-44         7.6   95878
9  tt7131622        4    45+         7.5   26383
...
```

etc.

This is the key step. It's similar to the `apply(pd.Series)` step you've tried, but the difference is in the `groupby`. This allows us to return many rows per movie_id, instead of pandas trying to interpret what we return as a single row. It feels a little like a hack, but hey, it works!

Now you can pivot on count & rating to get the tabulated values:

```
tabulated= parsed.pivot_table(
    index='movie_id',
    columns=['age'],
    values=['avg_rating','count'],
    aggfunc='mean'
)
```

I've used mean here, sum would also work **assuming there's only one row of data per film and age group**

```
> tabulated
          avg_rating                        count                             
age            18-29 30-44  45+  <18  all   18-29   30-44    45+   <18         all
movie_id                                                                      
tt1302006        8.3   7.9  7.8  8.7  8.1   41951   59729  18550   461      187675
tt7131622        7.9   7.6  7.5  8.4  7.8   82133   95878  26383   955      323152
tt7286456        8.7   8.5  8.3  9.1  8.6  160506  160158  30451  2244      592441
tt7653254        8.3   8.0  7.7  8.8  8.1   29740   33012   7875   318      109326
tt8579674        8.7   8.5  8.3  9.1  8.6    2437    2529    960    35        9420
tt8637428        7.9   7.6  7.3  8.0  7.7    5901    6492   2133    45       21362
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative method is to `set_index` with "movie_id" and `explode` the `rating_all` column (this creates a Series with duplicate indexes). Then cast it to a DataFrame constructor to build the preliminary DataFrame. Then use `pivot` on it to get the output in the desired format.

```
s = df.set_index('movie_id')['rating_all'].explode()
tmp = pd.DataFrame(s.tolist(), index = s.index).reset_index()
out = tmp.pivot('movie_id', 'age', ['avg_rating','count'])
```

Output:

```
          avg_rating                        count                             
age            18-29 30-44  45+  <18  all   18-29   30-44    45+   <18         all
movie_id                                                                      
tt1302006        8.3   7.9  7.8  8.7  8.1   41951   59729  18550   461      187675
tt7131622        7.9   7.6  7.5  8.4  7.8   82133   95878  26383   955      323152
tt7286456        8.7   8.5  8.3  9.1  8.6  160506  160158  30451  2244      592441
tt7653254        8.3   8.0  7.7  8.8  8.1   29740   33012   7875   318      109326
tt8579674        8.7   8.5  8.3  9.1  8.6    2437    2529    960    35        9420
tt8637428        7.9   7.6  7.3  8.0  7.7    5901    6492   2133    45       21362
```

It turns out, `set_index` + `explode` + `DataFrame` + `pivot` is quite a bit faster than `groupby` + `apply(DataFrame)` + `pivot_table`:

```
%timeit -n 1000 s = df.set_index('movie_id')['rating_all'].explode(); tmp = pd.DataFrame(s.tolist(), index = s.index).reset_index(); out = tmp.pivot('movie_id', 'age', ['avg_rating','count'])
%timeit -n 1000 s = df.groupby('movie_id').rating_all.apply(lambda x: pd.DataFrame(x.values[0])).reset_index(); out = s.pivot_table(index='movie_id', columns=['age'],values=['avg_rating','count'],aggfunc='mean')
```

```
5.1 ms ± 465 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
21.6 ms ± 1.53 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```